# ¿Cómo enviar un modelo con una lista de modelos mediante POST en mvc EF C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tengo un problema con un envío de un modelo a una función POST, no sé si algo estoy haciendo mal al setear la lista que tengo en el modelo pero todos los atributos que mando aparecen sea en cero o en nulos y no entiendo porque.

Modelo EvaluacionPreguntasDetailsView

```
        public int AprendizEvaluacionID { get; set; }
        public int EvaluacionID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Horas { get; set; }
        public List<EvaluacionPregunta> EvaluacionPreguntas { get; set; }
```

La lista que está en el modelo anterior esta contenida por la tabla enlace entre Evaluación y Preguntas, de aquí saco las preguntas para mostrarlas en las vistas que requiero, ahora bien, esto en la función GET y la visualización de datos me resulta perfectamente pero la cosa esta cuando intento enviar de la vista al controlador el mismo modelo pero modificado para hacer lo que pretendo hacer.

Un detalle importante es que la entidad Preguntas tiene un atributo llamado "Respuestas" donde este posee separado por "punto y coma" las respuestas y en la vista hago el respectivo código para que cada respuesta salga en un radio button cada una, es decir que si tengo 4 respuestas en este atributo, serán 4 radio buttons los que saldrán.

Vista GET

```
@model ASPXEvaluacion.Models.EvaluacionPreguntasDetailsView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Realizar Evaluación";
}

<h2>Realizar Evaluación</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Evaluación</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Fecha)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Horas)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Horas)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

@using ASPXEvaluacion.Utils;
<h3>Preguntas a realizar</h3>
@if (Model.EvaluacionPreguntas.Count == 0)
{
    <h4> No hay preguntas registradas para esta evaluación, comuniquese con su instructor </h4>
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AprendizEvaluacionID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EvaluacionID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Nombre)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Fecha)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Horas)
        <table class="table">
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.EvaluacionPreguntas.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@(i + 1)<text>. </text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.EvaluacionPreguntas[i].Preguntas.Question)</td>
                    </tr>
                    var preguntas = Model.EvaluacionPreguntas[i].Preguntas;
                    List<string> respuestas = preguntas.Respuestas.Split(';').ToList();
                    respuestas.Shuffle();
                    foreach (string item in respuestas)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(itemPregunta => Model.EvaluacionPreguntas[i].Preguntas.Respuestas, item, new { id = "" })
                                @item
                                @Html.HiddenFor(itemPregunta => item)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </table>
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="RealizarEvaluacion" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Este código me funciona de perlas (la función Shuffle es un aleatorizador de lista para que las respuestas no ubiquen en la misma posición siempre, además la primera respuesta antes del primer punto y coma es la respuesta correcta) y me muestra los datos como tal pero al momento de hacer submit, la función POST no me setea los datos enviado a la vista sino que me los setea en ceros o nulos.

Funciones GET y POST del controlador

```
public ActionResult RealizarEvaluacion(int? idEvaluacion, int? idAprendizEvaluacion)
        {
            if (idEvaluacion == null || idAprendizEvaluacion == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Evaluacion evaluacion = db.Evaluacions.Find(idEvaluacion);
            if (evaluacion == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var view = new EvaluacionPreguntasDetailsView
            {
                AprendizEvaluacionID = (int) idAprendizEvaluacion,
                EvaluacionID = evaluacion.EvaluacionID,
                Nombre = evaluacion.Nombre,
                Fecha = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", evaluacion.Fecha),
                Horas = string.Format("{0:t} - {1:t}", evaluacion.HoraInicio, evaluacion.HoraFinal),
                EvaluacionPreguntas = evaluacion.EvaluacionPreguntas.ToList(),
            };
            return View(view);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RealizarEvaluacion(EvaluacionPreguntasDetailsView evaluacionPreguntas)
        {
            code...
        }
```

Es justo en la función POST que no me capta el modelo que necesito, no sé si al momento de crear los radio buttons algo indebido estoy haciendo o el binding no se realiza adecuadamente o qué se yo, no llevo mucho desarrollado en MVC con EF en C# pero me gustaría solucionar esto nada más, que se pueda enviar el modelo completo.

PD: El objetivo que visualizo (no sé si habrá una manera más sencilla) es que en el modelo de la vista, el atributo "Respuestas" sea seteado por el radio button seleccionado y al momento de mandarlo a la función POST este modelo sea comparado con las respuestas originales donde la primera respuesta antes del primer punto y coma sea verdadera y así puntuar el resultado, de caso contrario no se puntuaría y así no se sumaría a la nota final del examen; espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, solo me falta esto para seguir con el proceso y culminar este proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Termine encontrando la solución a mi problema buscando y buscando por Internet, aunque deduzco que fue más bien algo demasiado obvio por algunos post que daban la idea y yo no la notaba a primera vista.

Resulta que estaba utilizando la lista de EvaluacionPreguntas como mi set de las respuestas seleccionadas por cada radio button, esto hacía que el modelo se "dañará" y de este modo no mandaba los datos que debería (Sinceramente desconozco porque esto no funcionaba pero imagino que no se puede modificar un modelo dentro de otro modelo en una lista o bueno, que sé yo); entonces analizando el código de otras personas descubrí que el modelo debía contener otra propiedad que sirviera como base para contener la selección de los radios, entonces mi modelo quedo de esta manera:

```
        public int AprendizEvaluacionID { get; set; }
        public int EvaluacionID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Horas { get; set; }
        public List<EvaluacionPregunta> EvaluacionPreguntas { get; set; }
        public string[] Respuesta { get; set; }
```

Tuve que crear un array de strings para captar por cada grupo de radios la selección de uno de ellos, así que en la parte del controlador en la variable view quedo de esta forma:

```
        AprendizEvaluacionID = (int) idAprendizEvaluacion,
        EvaluacionID = evaluacion.EvaluacionID,
        Nombre = evaluacion.Nombre,
        Fecha = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", evaluacion.Fecha),
        Horas = string.Format("{0:t} - {1:t}", evaluacion.HoraInicio, evaluacion.HoraFinal),
        EvaluacionPreguntas = evaluacion.EvaluacionPreguntas.ToList(),
        Respuesta = new string[evaluacion.EvaluacionPreguntas.ToList().Count]
```

Y en el foreach de la vista quedo así:

```
        foreach (string item in respuestas)
        {
             <tr>
                  <td>
                         @Html.RadioButtonFor(itemPregunta => Model.Respuesta[i], item)
                         @item
                  </td>
             </tr>
         }
```

Así es como lo pude solucionar y bueno, por si alguien tiene la duda y aún no lo ha encontrado, pues aquí dejo mi propia solución